# Spring boot + jpa lazy fetch

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I'm new here, I hope you can help me guys.

I have a problem with the lazy fetch type.

I don't like to fetch all relationship, just if I need that.
When I use `CommandLineRunner.run` method, it's okay, it's fetching Lazily, but if I call that method from `RestController`, it's always fetching *eagerly* but I don't want that.

I tried:

- with DTO and without DTO object.
- upgrade all dependencies to the newest version.
- Change @RestController annotation to @Controller
- @Query annotation with LEFT JOIN FETCH on a custom method in the Repository
- @Lazy(value=true)
- @Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
- @LazyCollection(value = LazyCollectionOption.TRUE)
- @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
- @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
- And sure, I tried to put fetch = FetchType.LAZY and into the @ManyToMany, @ManyToOne... annotation and with cascade things too.
- Using @PersistenceContext private EntityManager manager with createQuery();

and finally, I'm using spring security with CustomUserDetailsService. When I log in it returns with the User object.
If the `@Transactional` annotation is on the ServiceImpl class it's fetching *eagerly*, but if I remove that annotation, it's fetch Lazily, but this is only working on login.

Do you have any idea?

Repository:

```
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Page;
import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor{
}
```

ServiceImpl:

```
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.User;
import hu.pte.clms.repository.UserRepository;
import hu.pte.clms.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService{

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public List<User> listAll(){
        return userRepository.findAll();
    }

    /* And another methods with this scheme */
```

Controller:

```
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.User;
import hu.pte.clms.model.dto.UserDTO;
import hu.pte.clms.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class UserController{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user/all", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<UserDTO>> listAll(){
        return new ResponseEntity<>(userService.listAll().stream().map(user ->
                new UserDTO(user.getId(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), user.getCity(), user.getCountry(), user.getBio(), user.getPictureUrl())).collect(Collectors.toList()), HttpStatus.OK);
        }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/auth/user")
    public LoginResult get(){
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(!auth.getName().equals("anonymousUser")){
            User user = userService.findByUsername(auth.getName());
            return new LoginResult(auth.getName(), auth.getAuthorities(), user);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

LoginResult:

```
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

public class LoginResult implements UserDetails{
    private String password;
    private String name;
    private User user;
    private Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities;

    public LoginResult(String name, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, User user){
        this.name = name;
        this.authorities = authorities;
        this.user = user;
    }

    public LoginResult(String username, String s, boolean b, boolean userNonExpired, boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean userNonLocked, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities){}

    public LoginResult(String username, String password, List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities){
        this.name = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.authorities = grantedAuthorities;
    }
```

User:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.relationship.UserSkill;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "USER")
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(value = JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class User implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "AGE")
    private Short age;

    @Column(name = "SEX")
    private String sex;

    @Column(name = "PHONE")
    private String phone;

    @Column(name = "SKYPE")
    private String skype;

    @Column(name = "PRIMARY_EMAIL")
    private String primaryEmail;

    @Column(name = "SECONDARY_EMAIL")
    private String secondaryEmail;

    @Column(name = "CITY")
    private String city;

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY")
    private String country;

    @Column(name = "BIO")
    private String bio;

    @Column(name = "PICTURE_URL")
    private String pictureUrl;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "CONFIG_ID")
    private Config config;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "REL_USER_ROLE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID")})
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "REL_USER_SECURITY_ROLE", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SECURITY_ROLE_ID")})
    private List<SecurityRole> securityRoles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private List<UserSkill> skills = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "REL_USER_PROJECT", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PROJECT_ID")})
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "reviewed", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

 /*Getters & setters*/
```

UserDTO:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.*;
import hu.pte.clms.model.domain.relationship.UserSkill;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
public class UserDTO{

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Short age;
    private String sex;
    private String phone;
    private String skype;
    private String primaryEmail;
    private String secondaryEmail;
    private String city;
    private String country;
    private String bio;
    private String pictureUrl;
    private Config config;
    private List<Role> roles = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<SecurityRole> securityRoles = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<UserSkill> skills = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Project> projects = new ArrayList<>();
    private List<Review> reviews = new ArrayList<>();

    public UserDTO(){
    }

    public UserDTO(User user){
        this.id = user.getId();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.age = user.getAge();
        this.sex = user.getSex();
        this.phone = user.getPhone();
        this.skype = user.getSkype();
        this.primaryEmail = user.getPrimaryEmail();
        this.secondaryEmail = user.getSecondaryEmail();
        this.city = user.getCity();
        this.country = user.getCountry();
        this.bio = user.getBio();
        this.pictureUrl = user.getPictureUrl();
        this.config = user.getConfig();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
        this.securityRoles = user.getSecurityRoles();
        this.skills = user.getSkills();
        this.projects = user.getProjects();
        this.reviews = user.getReviews();
    }

    public UserDTO(Long id, String firstName, String lastName, String city, String country, String bio, String pictureUrl){
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.city = city;
        this.country = country;
        this.bio = bio;
        this.pictureUrl = pictureUrl;
    }
    /*Getters & setters*/
}
```

Application.java:

```
import hu.pte.clms.service.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication(Application.class);
        app.setShowBanner(false);
        app.setRegisterShutdownHook(true);  
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... strings) throws Exception{
        userService.listAll();
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    ...

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.34</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Application.yml:

```
spring.datasource:
  url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clms?autoReconnect=true
  username: clms
  password: clms
  testOnBorrow: true
  validationQuery: SELECT 1
  driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

Comment: Could you please try to narrow down your problem, in order to not post your entire application code?

Comment: I shared it because maybe I went wrong in something and someone notices. I wrote my problem at the beginning, it is not required to go through the code.

Comment: As @aribeiro said, better try to provide a simplified example of what's going on, so people can test it. I don't see all the code useful to solve the case. Have a look at [this](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Okey guys, sorry about that. Next time I will use your suggestions.

Comment: What exactly is being eagerly fetched which shouldn't be?

Comment: I'd like the securityRoles eagerly and all others lazily.

Comment: I think I have found the reason . see this：
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33727017/configure-jackson-to-omit-lazy-loading-attributes-in-springboot

Answer (score 0):

**Sorry I cannot really write a comment so I am writing here.

The only thing I could see here is the @Transactional annotation in service class and default propagation is required.

One another thing, in Jackson @JsonIgnoreProperties and @JsonIgnore does not work along. Better put the properties to ignore in the @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"projects", "reviews"})

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I modified that. But unfortunately it did't change anything. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should perform mapping in DB, not in your code. i.e.

```
SELECT NEW package.UserDTO(user.id, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.city, user.country, user.bio, user.pictureUrl) FROM User user …
```

It's guaranteed that only fields from constructor will be fetched when you're using JPQL query like this.