# add MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

i want to add my Custom MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter to Spring Boot . it set successful as Converter but did not use it for converting ...

i see this error just for spring 4.3 and upper. it successful set in spring 4.0.3

How do i correct this converter ???

here is my code

```
public class ResponseViewEntity<T> extends
    ResponseEntity<ContainerViewEntity<T>> {

private Class<? extends View.Base> view;

public ResponseViewEntity(HttpStatus statusCode) {
    super(statusCode);
}

public ResponseViewEntity(T body, HttpStatus statusCode) {
    super(new ContainerViewEntity<T>(body, View.Base.class), statusCode);
}

public ResponseViewEntity(T body, Class<? extends View.Base> view, HttpStatus statusCode) {
    super(new ContainerViewEntity<T>(body, view), statusCode);
}
```

Converter :

```
public class JsonViewMessageConverter extends
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter {

private ObjectMapper objectMapper = new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();

protected Object readInternal(Class<?> clazz, HttpInputMessage inputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotReadableException {
    JavaType javaType = getJavaType(clazz);
    try {
        return objectMapper.readValue(inputMessage.getBody(), javaType);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException ex) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotReadableException("Could not read JSON: "
                + ex.getMessage(), (Throwable) ex);
    }
}

protected void writeInternal(Object object, HttpOutputMessage outputMessage)
        throws IOException, HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    if (object instanceof ContainerViewEntity
            && ((ContainerViewEntity) object).hasView()) {
        writeView((ContainerViewEntity) object, outputMessage);
    } else {
        super.writeInternal(object, outputMessage);
    }
}

protected void writeView(ContainerViewEntity view,
        HttpOutputMessage outputMessage) throws IOException,
        HttpMessageNotWritableException {
    JsonEncoding encoding = getJsonEncoding(outputMessage.getHeaders()
            .getContentType());
    ObjectWriter writer = getWriterForView(view.getView());
    JsonGenerator jsonGenerator = writer.getFactory().createGenerator(
            outputMessage.getBody(), encoding);
    try {
        writer.writeValue(jsonGenerator, view.getObject());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new HttpMessageNotWritableException("Could not write JSON: "
                + ex.getMessage(), (Throwable) ex);
    }
}

private ObjectWriter getWriterForView(Class<?> view) {
    objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
    return objectMapper.writer().withView(view);
}

protected JavaType getJavaType(Class<?> clazz) {
    return TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(clazz);
}

public ObjectMapper getObjectMapper() {
    return objectMapper;
}

protected JsonEncoding getJsonEncoding(MediaType contentType) {
    if (contentType != null && contentType.getCharset() != null) {
        Charset charset = contentType.getCharset();
        for (JsonEncoding encoding : JsonEncoding.values()) {
            if (!charset.name().equals(encoding.getJavaName()))
                continue;
            return encoding;
        }
    }
    return JsonEncoding.UTF8;
}

public void setObjectMapper(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
    Assert.notNull((Object) objectMapper,
            (String) "ObjectMapper must not be null");
    this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
}
```

and My config

```
@Bean
public JsonViewMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    JsonViewMessageConverter jsonConverter = new JsonViewMessageConverter();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new HibernateAwareObjectMapper();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}

@Override
public void configureMessageConverters(
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
    converters.add(mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
}
```

Comment: this has helped me https://stackoverflow.com/a/33727108/1681445